# JDOM2 and xmlns attribute

Tags: xml-namespaces, jdom-2

I'm generating sitemaps and their index with JDOM2.

what I'd like to obtain is this:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"><sitemap><loc>http://
```

so I added an attribute to the root element titled "xmlns". Running the code I receive this error:

```
The name "xmlns" is not legal for JDOM/XML attributes: An Attribute name may not be "xmlns"; use the Namespace class to manage namespaces.
```

How can I obtain what I need without changing the above structure?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use namespaces, not attributes:

```
Element root = new Element("sitemapindex", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
```

Read up on namespaces....:  http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Rolf